# Android EPG architecture design

Tags: android, user-interface, epg

I an planning to design a EPG (electronic program guide ) in androids .please help me in designing the EPG.
Many ideas flowing through but before moving further want to finalize.
I want to design EPG as in the image [image: EPG]

Will I use List fragments or table layout or different layout like relative with specifying the layout weight or fully list view (customized list view  )
any help is appreciated

Comment: can you please share me your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create custom ViewGroup that actually will be AdapterView. Write you own adapter interface that based on time and not on indexes. I have experience in writing epg component for android and custom components in general for android.

Comment: can u explain this in detail and give some related link so that it will be very useful

Comment: I also have to implement EPG on Android. If you could explain the idea how to do it I would appreciate it.

Comment: @alexandr.opara  traninho AndroidOptimist
Can you Please share the sample code or github link, I have to implement it for Android TV?

Comment: @traninho Can you Please share details

Comment: @alexandr.opara please share if you have any reference for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the source code of Live Channels (EPG view included) here: https://github.com/PerfsolTech/EPGView

It's based on RecyclerView so it's really efficient in terms of UX.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer nested recyclerviews.
You got one for vertical channels, another for horizontal timeline.
In the third one (epg) the viewholders also have horizontal recyclerviews which scrolling is synchronized with the timeline.